MIME type of "text/html"
I have project with turborepo and 2 react projects inside deployed on Vercel. Today I faced the problem, that on prod, when I navigate to https://website/results/report, it works well, but when I reload page, I have white page and error
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
This problem doesn't appear when I trying to reproduce it on localhost.
URL like https://website/results, https://website/login, https://website/ works well after reload.
I'll really appreciate if you help me.
{
   "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/((?!api/.*).*)",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
 }

vercel.json file
 "base": "./", in my vite.config.ts file
